# cx_freeze makes selenium unable to take screenshot in python

Tags: python, windows, selenium, screenshot, cx-freeze

I am using python 36 with selnium and everything works fine in pycharm. But after exporting it with cx_freeze, selenium seems to work but it just can't take screenshot.

```
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('screenshots/numbers.png')
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

(there is a folder named 'screenshots/')

Answer (score 0):

When you use cx-freeze the current directory may be different

```
import os 
print(os.getcwd())
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('screenshots/numbers.png')
```

Run above and make sure it gives you the correct path. If not them you know why it is not working